# zoom in and out of android screen

Tags: android, zooming

I want to zoom in out on any screen including home screen or any other app screen.I have tried to change Screen resolution by changing lcd_density in build.prop file by rooting device but it requires rebooting of device.Can't it be done just like iphone where text/screen zooming can be done at runtime without rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

This is an accessibility thing, most Android have a setting for this under settings>accessibility

If you search around on the web it should be there.

I have seen some rooted devices that let you change the default text size can't remember what the app was called though sorry.

Comment: I haven't found any such option in android handset like Samsung,Lg,Htc....Can you please be more specific about handsets

Comment: I know for sure the motorola defy has it, im pretty sure my tablet running 4.0.3 has it as well, acer iconia a500.

Comment: @SmartLemon isnt there a way to get this programatically